# new must be used for creating struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I am doing coding with leetcode. For the question of Two add numbers, my solution could not be accepted because I didn't use new when creating struct. Here is my code:

```
ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
struct ListNode temp(-1);
struct ListNode *pre = &temp;
bool PlusOne = false;
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int sum;
while (NULL != l1 || NULL != l2)
{

    if (NULL != l1)
    {
        val1 = l1->val;
        l1 = l1->next;
    }
    if (NULL != l2)
    {
        val2 = l2->val;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    if (PlusOne == true)
    {
        sum = (val1 + val2 + 1) % 10;
        PlusOne = (val1 + val2 + 1) / 10;
    }
    else
    {
        sum = (val1 + val2) % 10;
        PlusOne = (val1 + val2) / 10;
    }
    struct ListNode newNode(sum);
    pre->next = &newNode;
    pre = &newNode;
    val1 = 0;
    val2 = 0;

}
if (true == PlusOne)
{
    struct ListNode newNode(1);
    pre->next = &newNode;
}
pre = temp.next;
return pre;}
```

It said runtime error, but it works if I use *pre->next = new ListNode(1)* replacing of 
        *struct   ListNode newNode(1);
        pre->next = &newNode;*

Is there anyone knows why?

Comment: Your program is ill-formed. In three places, you setup a return address of an automatic variable that is destroyed on scope-exit. Any usage of said-address, including dereference and even evaluation, invokes *undefined behavior*. That you bore witness to it "working" on an given platform is irrelevant, and a testimonial in confusing *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. Invoking undefined behavior makes any such observation meaningless.

Comment: Style advice: Don't do this: `if (true == PlusOne)`. `PlusOne` is a boolean already, and you probably wouldn't do `if(true == (true == PlusOne))`

Comment: @milleniumbug, Please give more detail about this. I didn't understand what you meant. Thank you!

Comment: The if statement takes a boolean value, and executes instruction depending on if it's true or false. `PlusOne == true` is true if `PlusOne` is true, and is false if `PlusOne` is false. So it's redundant - just do `if (PlusOne)`. The same can be said about `PlusOne == false` - just do `!PlusOne`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It said runtime error, but it works if I use pre->next = new ListNode(1) replacing of struct ListNode newNode(1); pre->next = &newNode;

That's because you're pointing to a local variable which will be destroyed when the `if` block exists.

```
if (true == PlusOne)
{
    struct ListNode newNode(1);
    pre->next = &newNode;
}
```

`pre->next` would be pointing to unallocated memory when the control comes out of the `if` block. It's similar to doing this

```
int* get_int() {
    int a = 1;
    return &a;
}

void process_int() {
    int *p = get_int();
    // oops! p is pointing to unallocated memory; undefined behaviour ensues
    *p;
}
```

Never point to a local variable which doesn't outlive your pointer.

The reason why `new` works is that you're manually allocating memory in the freestore which will be alive until `delete` is called or the program exists (whichever is earlier).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But I have tested my version using VS studio, it also worked. I understood what you are saying. So here may be something about VC++?

Comment: The last code snippet above, where I wrote as undefined behaviour, may/may not work too i.e. when you tried accessing the memory it's not been reused for something else, so it may seem that it works; but it is a time bomb. Anytime something else is written on it, your program wouldn't work.

Comment: @YutaoXing See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/183120) for the reasons and to understand an important concept in C and C++.